# Javascript upload file size

Tags: javascript, file, upload, size

I need help with file size on upload. i'd like to add file maximum size 2MB.

I use javascript code and i'm not good with javascript so if you guys can add file size into my code. Thanks.

```js
var _validFileExtensions = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png"];    
function Validate(oForm) {
    var arrInputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrInputs.length; i++) {
        var oInput = arrInputs[i];
        if (oInput.type == "file") {
            var sFileName = oInput.value;
            if (sFileName.length > 0) {
                var blnValid = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < _validFileExtensions.length; j++) {
                    var sCurExtension = _validFileExtensions[j];
                    if (sFileName.substr(sFileName.length - sCurExtension.length, sCurExtension.length).toLowerCase() == sCurExtension.toLowerCase()) {
                        blnValid = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                if (!blnValid) {
                    alert("Sorry,   " + sFileName + " is invalid, allowed extensions are: " + _validFileExtensions.join(", "));
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
  
    return true;
}
```

Comment: client side validation of file is a very bad idea

Comment: @TonyRaoulIscaros can u share a good code for uploading files?

Comment: What's your server side framework/programming language ?

Comment: @TonyRaoulIscaros im usually using php but for upload files i want use javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php

Comment: @Hartman http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004

Comment: If you really want use Client side validation, you certainly have to change this code a lot! It is really inefficient. (no offense, since you yourself admit you are new to JS). By inefficient I mean performance issues. Can I change your code a little bit as well??

Comment: @SyedHuzaifaHassan ye you can if you want to :) i will apreciate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is the code I ended up writing

It can still be optimized in various ways, so its open for any performance, semantic or refactoring edits. I am not an expert.

## Code Explained

1. In `var _maxFilsize` you have to write size of max file size to be allowed in bytes.
2. `Function Validate` has parameter `oForm` which expects an `HTML object`, through which it can search for input fields.
3. Store all `input` elements in an array, `arrInputs`.
4. Store value of `arrInputs[i].type` in `string` form in variable `inputType`
5. Compare the value of `inputType` with different input types in `if/else` statements.
6. When condition is met, each block `returns` a `function` that validates the matched input field
7. Function `validateImage` takes an argument which is simply the input field's property that contains list of files selected by user, `arrInputs[i].files`.
8. In `validateImage` Function there is a for loop that iterates over the list of files and validates their `type` and `size`, and returns `true` or `false` depending upon validity of file.

### Code

```
var _maxFilesize = 2000000;// in bytes
function Validate(oForm) {
    var arrInputs = oForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var inputType;
    var i = 0;
    var arrLength = arrInputs.length;
    for (i; i < arrLength; i++) {
        inputType =arrInputs[i].type.toString();
        if (inputType === "file"){
            return validateImage(arrInputs[i].files);//calls function for validating image
        }else if(inputType === "email"){
            //call email validating function
        }//add validation for more fields
    }
}
function validateImage(file){
    var j = 0;
    var NumberOfFiles = file.length;
    for(j; j< NumberOfFiles;j++){
        if ((file[j].type === "image/jpeg" || file[j].type === "image/png")&& (file[j].size)<= _maxFilesize){
            return true //or whatever you want to do here like calling a function to upadate view, or something
        }
        else{
            return false //or whatever you want to do here like calling a function to upadate view, or something
        }
    }
}
```